# Cypher: return specific value on uniqueness constraint voilation

Tags: neo4j, cypher, unique-constraint

I have a uniqueness constraint on a node's property. When I do `CREATE` I get back `ConstraintValidationFailed` error if value already exists. How can I return a specific value from my Cypher query in such case instead of relying on constraint validation error?

For example, I would love to return `exists` string in case of a conflict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. This is the real purpose of constraints.

2 solutions :

a) You do a preliminary MATCH :

```
MATCH (u:User {login: "existinglogin"}) RETURN "exists" AS result
```

Will return the string "exist" if the node was existing, no records otherwise.

b) You take advantage of [MERGE](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/), where you can do operations when the node is matched or when the node is created.